# Angular 2 Failed to load resource error: status 404

Tags: angular

I was looking at a previous post were angular js 2 is being used to calculate the area of a rectangle: I'm new to angular 2, but was attempting to replicate the app, but when executed, I get:  Failed to load resource error: ...when viewed via the developer console:

the following is how I have my setup arranged:

**typescript file: app.componet.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Area of Rectangle';

onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    console.log(f.value);  
    console.log(f.valid);

}
```

**app.component.html**:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>

  <div>
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
      Length: <input [(ngModel)] = "length" /><br />
      Width: <input [(ngModel)] = "width" /><br />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

  <p>Length value: {{ length.value }}</p>
  <p>Length valid: {{ length.valid }}</p>

  <p>Width value: {{ width.value }}</p>
  <p>Width valid: {{ width.valid }}</p>


  <p>Form value: {{ f.value | json }}</p>
  <p>Form valid: {{ f.valid }}</p>

  <p>The result is: </p> {{f.value.length * f.value.width}}</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**index.html**:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

...could I get some help with this please?

Comment: So, what is the resource that can't be loaded? How are you running this application?

Comment: if you are using relative path in templateUrl, set the module to module.id or set the templateUrl to complete path.

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To use relative path, set the moduleID parameter of the component. Refer code snippet below:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

Comment: `module.id` has been deprecated for some time, see https://angular.io/guide/change-log : _"We strongly encourage you to only write component-relative paths. That is the only form of URL discussed in these docs. You no longer need to write @Component({ moduleId: module.id }), **nor should you.**"_

Comment: @msanford, the question is in Angular 2 if I am not wrong.

Comment: That is true, but _a lot_ of people use "Angular 2" as a synonym for "Angular 2 and above". That said, it is unclear in the OP.

Comment: @msanford, thanks. I gave the answer based on the subject that it is in Angular 2. Will keep this is mind for future answers.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms#two-way-data-binding-with-ngmodel)

> The NgForm directive supplements the form element with additional
>   features. It holds the controls you created for the elements with an
>   ngModel directive and **name attribute**, and monitors their properties,
>   including their validity.

You haven't added `name` attribute. Which would now result in the following error

> If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute
>   must be set or the form
>         control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions

```
 <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
      Length: <input  name="length" [(ngModel)] = "length" /><br />
      Width: <input name="width" [(ngModel)] = "width" /><br />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```